# I need a GPath query to select a node using a numeric index

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, gpath

How do I select from a parsed html document a specific element given its index.

For example:
...

```
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
```

I want to select the second `div` but it seems to me GPath doesn't offer a solution like Xpath does.

Answer (score 7):

```
def html = """
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
  </body>
</html>"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(html)

assert xml.body.div[0].text() == "div1"
assert xml.body.div[1].text() == "div2"
```

You can also use collection type methods on the div node such as .each/.find, for example:

```
xml.body.div.find { it.text() == "div2" }
```

EDIT:

To clarify my answer a bit, given HTML in the same structure as the sample I listed above but with various content, you can always access the second div using array index 1:

```
xml.body.div[1]
```

Comment: i don't know the content of the divs but i know that the info that is important for me is in the second one ...

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify it a bit.  The asserts were just there to show which content it accessed.  Using div[1] should get you the second div node.